# Angular2: Install external library using npm through Maven

Tags: java, node.js, angular, maven, ng2-charts

Am building an `Angular2` `SpringBoot` application which I need to deploy directly to a container like `tomcat` like a `war` file. Am able to successfully do that by install `npm` pluging in maven like:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- It will install nodejs and npm -->
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v9.2.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory 
                    to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now, am also using [Ng2Charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2charts) library to build `highcharts` on UI. I can simply run `npm install ng2charts` and would be good to go but I want to install these during `mvn clean install` because I don't want to create an added `npm` dependency on production.

Is there a way I can install these libraries using maven?

I tried something line:

```
<execution>
    <id>ng2charts</id>
    <goals>
            <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
            <arguments>install</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

But it gives me error saying:

```
[ERROR] [0m[1m[31mERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(48,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'[39m[22m[0m
[ERROR] [0m[1m[31m  Could not resolve ng2-charts relative to /Users/user/Documents/workspace/MyPortal/src/frontend/src/app/app.module.ts..[39m[22m[0m
[ERROR] [0m[1m[31msrc/app/chart/chart.component.ts(5,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.[39m[22m[0m
[ERROR] [0m[1m[31msrc/app/app.module.ts(23,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-charts'.[39m[22m[0m
[ERROR] [0m[1m[31m[39m[22m[0m.............
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, i figured out a way to include external dependencies in Angular. We just need to update `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ng2-charts": "^1.1.0",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1"
}
```

This loads the libraries.